# Java check if microphone input is muted

Tags: java, audio, microphone, javasound

I'm trying to make a simple program that checks if a microphone is muted or not. This is the code I have for determine which `Line` the microphone is.

```
private Line getMic() throws LineUnavailableException {

    Mixer.Info[] mixerInfos = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

    for (int i = 0; i < mixerInfos.length; i++) {
        Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfos[i]);
        int maxLines = mixer.getMaxLines(Port.Info.MICROPHONE);
        Port lineIn = null;
        if (maxLines > 0) {

            lineIn = (Port) mixer.getLine(Port.Info.MICROPHONE);
            return lineIn;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then from there I call the following:

```
BooleanControl muteControl = (BooleanControl)mic.getControl(BooleanControl.Type.MUTE);
System.out.println(muteControl.getValue());
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
Unsupported control type: Mute
```

I went ahead and looked to see what `Controls` were available for the `Line` using the following:

```
for(Control c : mic.getControls()){
    System.out.println(c.getType());
}
```

There is only one `Control` and it is the `Master Volume`. I'm not sure why the `Mute` control is not listed.

The line that is being returned in my `getMic()` function is returning the correct microphone. I have a USB headset plugged in and it is recognized by any application.

Comment: Some controls are only available when the line is open.

Comment: @greg-449 I opened the line with `mic.open()` and confirmed it was open with `mic.isOpen()` but I still don't have the Mute control.

Comment: Sadly there is no guarantee that all controls are available

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The various audio control lines are not guaranteed to be implemented. I'm not sure why, but I think it has to do with the OS and local audio software which can vary considerably.

From [Processing Audio with Controls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/controls.html) (the last section *Manipulating the Audio Data Directly*):

> The Control API allows an implementation of the Java Sound API, or a
>   third-party provider of a mixer, to supply arbitrary sorts of signal
>   processing through controls. But what if no mixer offers the kind of
>   signal processing you need? It will take more work, but you might be
>   able to implement the signal processing in your program. Because the
>   Java Sound API gives you access to the audio data as an array of
>   bytes, you can alter these bytes in any way you choose.

For this reason, I tend to avoid using the control lines, and where possible, write code to accomplish the desired functionality. For example, one can manually access the individual frames of a `SourceDataLine` or `TargetDataLine`.

IDK how to test for "mute" on the microphone, but testing for incoming volume is doable using an RMS algorithm on the incoming PCM data points.

Comment: It's a poor reflection on SO's representation of [top user](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/topusers) for a tag when I 'outrank' the guru. Always a pleasure to read your answers on the subject.

Comment: Thanks! You've been helping people here for a long time, starting well before I did. Your rank is well earned. But also, I wonder if people do less up-voting of answers these days than in years before.

Comment: *"less up-voting of answers"* Not sure in a general sense, but I do think it's true of APIs which are lesser used now. For one example, I recently was working on an app and decided to use the Java-FX [`MediaPlayer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html) instead of Java Sound. It has the disadvantage of being a higher level API with less access to the data lines that I used to create 'interesting' animations to go with the music. But on the plus side, it supported MP3 out of the box and had an inbuilt FFT to provide a sound spectrum animation.